# "Running through an appropriate sequence" in proof of L2 Completeness

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

In Beals' *Analysis: an Introduction*, there is a proof that L2 is complete. I follow the proof, except for one last comment.  I will sketch the proof here for context:

> Given a Cauchy sequence $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, choose a subsequence
>   $(g_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ such that
>
> $$\|g_{n+1} - g_n \|_2 \leq 2^{-n}. $$
>
> For a bounded interval $A$, we have by Cauchy Schwartz,
>
> $$\int_A |g_{n+1}-g_n| \leq \|g_{n+1} - g_n\| m(A)^{1/2}.$$
>
> It follows that $f(x) = \lim g_n(x)$ exists almost everywhere in $A$,
>   so it also exists almost everywhere in $\mathbb R$.
>
> Now, we need to show that $\|g_n -f\|_2 \rightarrow 0$, and let $h$ be
>   any element of $L^2$.  Then,
>
> $$[f(x) - g_n(x)] h(x)  = \sum_{k=n}^\infty [ g_{k+1}(x) - g_k(x) ]h(x)$$
>
> $$|(f-g_n,h) | \leq \sum_{k=n}^\infty \|g_{k+1} - g_k \|_2 \|h\|_2 \leq 2^{1-n} \|h\|_2$$
>
> We let $h=f-g_n$, and then
>
> $$\|f-g_n\|_2^2 \leq 2^{1-n} \| f-g_n\|_2$$
>
> so $\|f-g_n\|_2 \leq 2^{1-n}$.
>
> Which completes the proof.

The author remarks, though, that "**Strictly speaking, we should let $h$ run through an appropriate $f-g_n$, since we do not know ahead of time that $f-g_n$ is actually square integrable.**"

Indeed, I recognize that to be a serious problem. It might not even make sense to write $\|f-g_n\|_2$. I'm just not sure how running through an appropriate sequence solve the problem. Can you help me make this explicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one standard argument:

Choose $N$ such that $\|g_n-g_m\| \le 1$ for all $n,m \ge N$.

Note that $\liminf_n g_n(x)-g_N(x)| = |f(x)-g_N(x)|$ for ae. $x$.

Fatou gives $\int |f(x)-g_N(x)| \le \liminf_n \|g_n-g_N\| \le 1$.

Hence $f-g_N$ is in $L^2$ and hence so is $f = (f-g_N)+g_N$.