# Orthogonal basis of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^2(\mathbb{R^+})$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $\mathbb{R}^+ = [0, \infty)$, i.e. the positive real numbers.
Let $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)$ be the sets of real-valued functions with domains in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^+$ respectively that are square integrate with respect to the Lebesgue measure. These sets are endowed with the inner product
$$
\left( f, g \right) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f g \ \mathsf{d} x,
$$
and
$$
\left( f, g \right) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f g \ \mathsf{d} x,
$$
respectively.

I have the following questions

1. Are the sets $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)$ separable Hilbert Spaces?.
2. In such a case, what Schauder basis exist for these sets?. Is there an known orthogonal family of functions on these sets?

**Motivation:** For the case $L^2(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is compact, this is known to be true. The families of orthogonal functions on this set are used in a wide range of engineering applications, e.g. solving PDES in compact domains. However, I have not found similar results when $\Omega$ is unbounded. The existence of an orthogonal set of functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)$ would be useful to solve problems in unbounded domains.

Comment: You can always glue together bases of, say, $[n,n+1)$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ (in the case of $\mathbb{R}^+$), or $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ (in the case of $\mathbb{R}$). I'm not sure how useful these are though.

Comment: https://mathstat.slu.edu/~freeman/FPT_Positive_basis.pdf ?

Comment: Thank you @Jose27, four your comment. However, that idea is not clear to me. For example, consider the basis of polynomials. I we glue together the constant function (e.g. $f(t)=1$) infinitely many times, we will end up with a function which is not $L^2$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Sorry, maybe gluing was the wrong word to use. Basically you just consider the bases of $L^2[n,n+1)$ as elements of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, say, by setting them equal to zero outside of $[n,n+1)$. This union of bases gives an orthonormal basis for the whole space.

Answer (score 4):

Start with an orthonormal basis $\{ \varphi_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ on $[0,1]$ with respect to ordinary Lebesgue measure. Then perform a change of variables from $[0,\infty)$ to $[0,1)$ such as $u(x)=1-e^{-x}$. Then
$$
     \int_0^1 f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx=\int_0^{\infty}f(u(x))\overline{g(u(x))}u'(x)dx
  = \int_{0}^{\infty}[f(u(x))e^{-x/2}]\overline{g(u(x))][e^{-x/2}]}dx
$$
Therefore, $\Phi : L^2[0,1]\rightarrow L^2[0,\infty)$ is a unitary map, where
$$
            (\Phi f)(x)= f(u(x))e^{-x/2}.
$$
In this way, any orthonormal basis $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of $L^2[0,1]$ is mapped to an orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,\infty)$ through $\Phi$.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is not difficult to prove that $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^2(\mathbb{R}_+)$ are Hilbert spaces. They are inner product spaces. Their completeness is a rather technical exercise in measure theory. Here is an example (the proof uses Fatou's lemma):

["Running through an appropriate sequence" in proof of L2 Completeness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845562/running-through-an-appropriate-sequence-in-proof-of-l2-completeness)

$L^2(\mathbb{R})$ has a countable basis. It consists of Hermite functions.
$L^2(\mathbb{R}_+)$ has a countable basis. It consists of Laguerre functions. Here is a link:

[On the completeness of the generalized Laguerre polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100461/on-the-completeness-of-the-generalized-laguerre-polynomials)

But separability is much easier to prove. Here is a bit more general statement.

> *$L^p(\mathbb{R})$ is separable ($1 \leq p < \infty$).*

**Proof.** Let $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$. We know that $|f|^p$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to standard Lebesgue measure only if for any positive $\varepsilon$ there exists a natural $n$ s.t.
$$
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}/[-n,n]} |f|^p \, d\mu < \varepsilon
$$
i.e. on the subset $\mathbb{R}/[-n,n]$ $f$ can be approximated by zero.

Denote $L^p_0 [-n,n]$ a countable dense subset of $L^p [-n,n]$. Using the indicator of $[n,-n]$ we can embed $L^p [-n,n]$ in $L^p (\mathbb{R})$. Thus, the subset
$$
L^p_0 (\mathbb{R}) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} L^p_0 [-n,n]
$$
of $L^p (\mathbb{R})$ is dense. As it is obviously countable we are done.

The statement for $L^p (\mathbb{R}_+)$ is a simple corollary.

Comment: Are the Hermite and Laguerre Functions the Hermite and Laguerre Polynomials?  Hermite and Laguerre Polynomials are **not** $L^2$ **with respect to the Lebesgue measure** in ether $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^+$. They are $L^2$ with respect to the measure represented by the "weight factor" they use, i.e. the density of custom measures that decay at infinity.

Comment: @RafaelRojas Yes, sure, the functions are not the polynomials. They can be obtained from the polynomials exactly by multiplying by the square root of the respective weight factor. Sometimes they are called generalized polynomials or something like that.